# Ввод строки char

Tags: c++

```
int n;
std::cout << "Введите количество символов:";
std::cin >> n;
char* stroka[1000];
std::cout << "Введите символы:";
std::cin >> stroka;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (stroka[i] == "a" and stroka[i + 1] == "b" and stroka[i + 2] == "c" and stroka[i + 3] == "d") {
        i += 4;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << stroka[i];
    }
}
```

не могу ввести символы, подчеркивает красным >>, как исправить?

Comment: 1. приведите код целиком (может у вас там функции `main` нет); 2. кто подчёркивает? 3. код-то компилируется и запускается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимый вам код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout << "Введите количество символов:";
    std::cin >> n;
    char stroka[1000];
    std::cout << "Введите символы:";
    std::cin >> stroka;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (stroka[i] == 'a' && stroka[i + 1] == 'b' && stroka[i + 2] == 'c' && stroka[i + 3] == 'd') {
            i += 4;
        }
        else {
        std::cout << stroka[i];
    }
}
}
```

Что исправлено:

1. Неправильное объявление массива

   `char* stroka[1000]; ->  char stroka[1000];`
2. `stroka[i] == "a" and stroka[i + 1] == "b" and stroka[i + 2] == "c" and stroka[i + 3] == "d"` заменено на

   `stroka[i] == 'a' && stroka[i + 1] == 'b' && stroka[i + 2] == 'c' && stroka[i + 3] == 'd'`

Вы пытаетесь сравнить `char` со `string`. Для `char` используются одинарные кавычки (`'`).